# Как вызвать JS функцию на html странице запросом от ОС?

Tags: javascript, debian, google-chrome, chromium

Есть html страница с javascript сценарием, всё это открыто на локальной машине c debian в chromium, как я могу вызывать функции из сценария на этой странице средствами ОС?

*PS пробовал xdotool и обработку нажатия клавиш на JQ - костыль на костыле*

UPD: решил вопрос через веб-сокеты. На "серверной части" открыл сокет и шлю когда необходимо команду, а в "клиентской части" на JS жду данные с этого сокета и запускаю свою функцию.

Comment: Уточните, какого рода запрос от ос вас интересует? Это некий bash скрипт или событие системы? Почитайте про api которое вам предоставляет хром, если то что вы хотите сделать возможно, подход там

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это не совсем событие системы - это прерывание GPIO, которое обрабатывает стороння библиотека на С++, а затем уже выполняет bash скрипт